# Copy Content from Sharepoint2007 to another Sharepoint2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a Sharepoint 2007 web farm installation with two site collections, one is a blank site and the other is a migrated Sharepoint 2003 site collection.

I want to move some specific content from the migrated 2003 collection to the 2007 collection, however I also want to change the path of where it exists, an example is that in the migrated 2003 collection HR is under Admin > HR, in the 2007 collection I want HR to appear before Admin.

I've looked around but haven't found a lot of information regarding how to move specific content between sites, any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer to this question was to use the backup / restore methods which are described well at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766807(office.12,printer).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was to use the backup / restore methods which are described well at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766807(office.12,printer).aspx